# Object has been destroyed Exception after reopen BrowserWindow on button click in Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am new to Electron Framework, developing simple desktop application with Electron.
Problem is that, when i open a new window in electron app and close it using menu bar close button and again try to open it, then it throws "Object has been destroyed Exception". How do i retain BrowserWindow object even though close button clicked???

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BrowserWindow object is supposed to be destroyed when closed.  You'll need to instantiate a new one when reopening instead of trying to reuse the reference.

Edit:

How you instantiate it depends on if you're doing it from the main process (i.e. "Main.js") or the renderer process.

From the main process, it would look like:

```
var electron = require("electron");
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");
var newWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 500
});

newWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/SomeStuff.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

If instantiating from the renderer process, you need to use the "remote" object to access the main process.  So it'd be like:

```
var newWindow = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 500
});
```

Comment: I know its object has been destroyed after closing it, But where should i instantiate it again?? Trying to instantiate after button click but giving "BrowserWindow is not a constructor" error

Comment: I added an example.  I was on my phone for the first post.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes across this and the other answer didn't help. I was having a similar issue where I was handling the closing of a window. I fixed it by using `window.destroy()` instead of `window.close()`