# Error: Object has been destroyed when trying to re-open a second BrowserWindow - Electron.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-window

In an electron-react-typescript app I use a button in the mainwindow to open a new window.
If I close this second window clicking on the 'x' on the top-tight corner,
when clicking the button in the mainwindow I get this message:
`"Error invoking remote method. TypeError: Object has been destroyed"`.
I found this: [Object has been destroyed Exception after reopen BrowserWindow on button click in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806556/object-has-been-destroyed-exception-after-reopen-browserwindow-on-button-click-i)  .
But that suggestion doesn't help me, because clicking on the button in the mainwindow I call this function :

```
window.api.electronIpcOn('window-A-opened')
```

which already activate the function in main.ts :

```
ipcMain.handle("open-type-A-window")

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
  mainWindow = null;
  WindowTypeA = null;

  //WindowTypeA.destroy();

});
```

I also tried with a windowsList: main.ts

```
let windowsList = []; const windowDestroy = (win) {
  let i = windowsList.indexOf(win);
  if (i > -1) {
    windowsList.splice(i, 1);
    win = null;
  }
}

const createWindow = (): void => { 
  windowsList.push(WindowTypeA);

  WindowTypeA.on('closed', function () {
    windowDestroy(WindowTypeA);
  });
}
```

but still the same error:  `"Error invoking remote method. TypeError: Object has been destroyed"`

.... So... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!! By splitting the creation of the windows: mainwindow and second-window :

```
const createWindowTypeA = (): void => {

}


const createWindow = (): void => {

}
```